# How can I create a reusable function in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

How can I create a resuable function/formula I can use in formulas in a spreadsheet?  In particular I need a very simple DateDiff formula and would like a way to encapsulate this function:

```
=(((HOUR(B3) * 60) * 60) + (MINUTE(B3) * 60) + SECOND(B3)) - (((HOUR(A3) * 60) * 60) + (MINUTE(A3) * 60) + SECOND(A3))
```

(Thanks to [Phil Winstanley](http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2007/01/14/excel-datediff-in-seconds.aspx))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [link](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/user-defined-functions.html) completely describes how to do it... instructions have been enumerated below:

1. Open up a new workbook.
2. Get into VBA (Press Alt+F11)
3. Insert a new module (Insert > Module)
4. Enter the Excel User Defined Function (UDF) in VBA
5. Get out of VBA (Press Alt+Q)
6. Use the functions (in the worksheet) - They will appear in the Paste Function dialog box, Shift+F3, under the "User Defined" category)

It's for Excel-2003, but the process is the same

You create a VBA module with a function, say NEWfunction,
then reference it in the cell, `=NEWfunction("A1")`.

Comment: This is called a UDF, user-defined function.

Comment: Sounds perfect, trying it now.

Answer (score 2):

While a VBA UDF is probably the best way to go. The formula you have could be simplified to

```
=MOD((B3-A3)*86400,86400)
```

because of the way Excel stores Date/Times as doubles